# How to access variable of variable inside sysevalf. Character operand was found, expecting numeric operand?

Tags: loops, variables, sas, sas-macro

I have a macro variable named bal_Sheet having certain column names which contain numeric values under them.

```
%let bal_Sheet = a1 a2 a3 a4;
```

I am trying to access this variables in the `sysevalf` function like

```
data abc.xyz;
  set abc.hfg;
  keep &bal_Sheet;

  %let char = sysevalf(&bal_Sheet/25, integer);
run;
quit;
```

And I am getting ,

> the character operand was found in the `%EVAL` function or `%IF` where
>   a numeric operand is required.

Please Help.

Thanks,

Comment: How is SAS supposed divide a string of variable names by 25?

Comment: @Tom It has numbers in it.

Comment: No, it has the text a1 a2 a3 a4. Are you expecting those to be variables in the dataset that hold numeric values?

Comment: @Reeza yes. Exactly.

Comment: @Reeza Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your attempt in its current form doesn't make sense. The macro variable would only hold the last value. What are you trying to do overall. Please add your answer as an edit to the question.

Comment: Agree with @Reeza At the very least, please follow up by saying what you're going on to use `&char` for, otherwise it's impossible to know how to solve this. Please edit the question rather than adding in the comments.

Comment: Explain what you want to happen. Preferably with example input data and results.  You should figure out the SAS statements that you need to use to get those results before attempting to use macro variables or macro logic to generate the statements.

Comment: Do you have a macro variable which holds lots of numbers separated by space and you want to divide each one of them 25 and store like they were stored earlier...i.e. separated by space?

Comment: Are you trying to divide the values of each variable `a1 a2 a3 a4` by 25?  `%let char =`  is going to run before any Data Step code, and it's going to try and divide the string "`a1 a2 a3 a4`" by 25, which is an invalid argument to `%sysevalf`. In that case, you'd want to look into something where you keep those variables, then use a loop over `array[*] _NUMERIC_` to divide each one by 25. If you're not trying to do that, then I don't know what the overall goal is and we need more information.